# Could not open the editor: Editor could not be initialized. NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I can import the Play2 project in eclipse, and work on scala files, but the problem is I can't open view files likes 'index.scala.html'. When I try to open the file I get following error.

**Could not open the editor: Editor could not be initialized.**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/util/parsing/input/Positional
at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.lexical.TemplatePartitionTokeniser.getScalaCommentAndPlainRegions(TemplatePartitionTokeniser.scala:28)
at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.lexical.TemplatePartitionTokeniser.tokenise(TemplatePartitionTokeniser.scala:66)
at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateTextRegionsComputer.tokens$lzycompute(TemplateRegionParser.scala:98)
at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateTextRegionsComputer.tokens(TemplateRegionParser.scala:96)
at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateTextRegionsComputer.<init>(TemplateRegionParser.scala:128)
at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateRegionParser.reset(TemplateRegionParser.scala:84)
................
```

But there is no problem opening other files. I don't know what's wrong. 
btw, I used typesafe-activator to create play project.

I will appreciate any suggestions, solutions or workarounds to make it work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1.Clean your project and build once
2.Just go to tab menu select newwindow from tab window

> i were solved with first two steps thanks

still you facing the problem please restart it.