# Eclipse : Could not open editor after Eclipse PDT upgrade to version 5.0.1.201706221952

Tags: java, php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I just upgraded my Eclipse PHP IDE by downloading Eclipse PDT Version 5.0.1.201706221952 but that was a bad idea since I can't work with Eclipse anymore. I think I'm facing a bug because I could not open any files of my project, the Eclipse file Editor seems broken. The DLTK indexing seems broken too (for my current project at least...). Sometimes the editor could open one of my files but the name of the file is not displayed and I can't save modifications.

I tried to clean my project since I've found a similiar issue ([Could not open the editor: Editor could not be initialized. NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133755/could-not-open-the-editor-editor-could-not-be-initialized-noclassdeffounderror)) but I got a building workspace error.

**Any idea on how I can get the Eclipse editor working ?**

---

- Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
- Build id: 20170314-1500
- My project uses Symfony 3 (could give more details if required)

---

Building workspace error :

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Script Builder' on project 'PROJET_VISA_ECLIPSE'.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/eclipse/php/internal/core/compiler/ast/visitor/PHPASTVisitor
```

Error at launch:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Initialize DLTK".
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/eclipse/php/internal/core/compiler/ast/visitor/PHPASTVisitor
```

Dubture plugin is also encountering errors :

```
com.dubture.twig.core.index.TwigIndexingVisitorExtension.
```

Editor error: No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.ui.internal.emptyEditorTab

```
java.lang.Exception
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createErrorPart(EditorReference.java:340)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:321)
```

Comment: I'm in the same trouble. I tried also to upgrade to eclipse Oxygen and update java sdk but nothing change

Comment: I've run to the same situation, and reported to Eclipse bug tracker : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519223

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem seems to come from an incompatibility between the new PDT version and the Symfony plugin.

I have the same error in both version of Eclipse (4.6 and 4.7, with PDT at 5.0.1), and just uninstalling the Symfony plugin (along with Twig plugin) works for me.

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks ! Editor is back but the lost of Symfony and Twig plugins is quite annoying :/ I will update this question again when the bug is corrected and the compatibility problem solved.

Comment: The Twig plugin from dubture doesn't seem to be incompatible with Oxygen. You don't have all of Symfony plugin, but it's not so bad, maybe

Comment: Just filed https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/issues/253 which hopefuly reaches the Symfony plugin devs.

Comment: There seems to be a 1.4 release of the Symfony Dubture plugin available, but no clue how to install it yet.

Comment: The update site has been updated and v 1.4 is now available for upgrades from Neon to Oxygen, and the problem seems to be fixed.